# unity-team 404 error after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I upgraded from Beta 2 to 12.04 final using the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

It appears everything upgraded except I get the following error message at the end.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does it mean and how do I proceed to fix it?